# Suspend one task for several iterations

Tags: c#, async-await, suspend

I was wondering if it is possible to suspend one task to a specific number of iteration (instead of specific timing)?

For example, I have this array of tasks and I would like to suspend one of the tasks in the array in the iterations where  0 < j < 3 .

```
int iteration = 0;
var tasksArray = new Task[NUM_THREADS];

for (int j = 0; j < NUM_REPEAT_THREADS; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
    {
        tasksArray[i] = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            iteration++;
            Console.WriteLine("Task" + iteration);
        });
       tasksArray[i].Wait();

    }
    iteration = 0;
}

Task.WaitAll(tasksArray);
```

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve with this? Why are you waiting every time you create a Task and then awaiting the array, which will always have already completed? Also, what is exactly `suspend`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using Task.Run, you can use new Task() and task.Start() to control when to start task (in your case where 0 < j < 3)

```
Task task = new Task(() => { 
                            iteration++;
                            Console.WriteLine("Task" + iteration); 
                         });
task.Start();
```

A task may be started and run only once. Any attempts to schedule a task a second time will result in an exception.

**It's recommended to user Task.Run or Task.Factory.StartNew (and not use task.Start) unless you have reason to use task.Start())**. One of case when you do this is when you need to separate the task's creation from its execution, such as when you conditionally execute tasks that you've created.

From more detail:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270682(v=vs.110).aspx

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2010/06/13/task-factory-startnew-vs-new-task-start/

Also line below results in sync wait for task to finish.

```
  tasksArray[i].Wait();
```

Ideally only Task.WaitAll(tasksArray) should be used. It will wait for all tasks to finish (and no blocking on individual task)

Comment: `WhenAll` method also can do that without blocking the thread